# Communicating between UIViewController and UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UITableView` (amongst other views).

The `UITableView` could get its cells from one of two `UITableDataSource`, depending on some condition.

My `UITableDataSource` class also acts as my `UITableViewDelegate`.

When a cell is selected (`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) I may want to perform an action on the `UIViewController`, such as `performSegue` or show an alert.

What would be the best way to do this?

1. Add a weak reference to the `UIViewController` inside each datasource/delegate class
2. Create a delegate per datasource/delegate class which calls functions inside my `UIViewController`
3. *Your suggestion here!*

I considered making my `UIViewController` the `UITableViewDelegate` but as the cells are different depending on the source I thought it would get messy.

> *Note*: I say "best way" but really I am just interested in alternate approaches

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is to subclass UITableViewController and implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableDataSource` there. You can return whichever cell you require in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`based on any state in your controller class.

Comment: I have already subclassed UIViewController and usually that would also be my delegate. But in this case as I have to pick between two completely different table views, I wanted to have two separate data sources instead.

Comment: For example, I use a segmented control to switch between 3 different data sets in a single table view. The UITableViewController subclass references the segmented control and three arrays of data. I then override 'numberOfRowsInSection', 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' and any other data source funcs to provide data depending on the state of the segment control.  When the segment controls switches to a new segment, just call tableView.reloadData to draw in the new data.